# Write string to fixed-length byte array in C#

Tags: c#, string, arrays

somehow couldn't find this with a google search, but I feel like it has to be simple...I need to convert a string to a fixed-length byte array, e.g. write "asdf" to a `byte[20]` array. the data is being sent over the network to a c++ app that expects a fixed-length field, and it works fine if I use a `BinaryWriter` and write the characters one by one, and pad it by writing '\0' an appropriate number of times.

is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str, int length) 
{
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.PadRight(length, ' '));
}
```

Comment: This will pad the buffer with spaces (0x20), not the null character (0x0) mentioned by the poster.  Otherwise this is great.

Comment: This doesn't work if the text is longer than `length`. If we have 50 bytes long string, and we use this method with `length` parameter 30, we got 50 bytes long byte array instead of 30.

Answer (score 13):

This is one way to do it:

```
  string foo = "bar";

  byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(foo);

  Array.Resize(ref bytes, 20);
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
String str = "hi";
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[20];
int len = str.Length > 20 ? 20 : str.Length;
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.Substring(0, len)).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
```

Comment: @Reed Good call.  I've fixed that bug.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx).

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[20];
Array.Copy(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString), byteArray, System.Math.Min(20, myString.Length);
```

Comment: using System.Math.Min is a smart approach.

Answer (score 1):

With unsafe code perhaps?

```
unsafe static void Main() {
    string s = "asdf";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
    fixed(char* c = s)
    fixed(byte* b = buffer) {
        Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(c, s.Length, b, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

(the bytes in the buffer will default to 0, but you can always zero them manually)

Answer (score 1):

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[20];
String str = "blah";

System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
bytes = encoding.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: Last line will overwrite your `bytes` with a new array length of 4.

Answer (score 1):

And just for completeness, LINQ:

```
(str + new String(default(Char), 20)).Take(20).Select(ch => (byte)ch).ToArray();
```

For variation, this snippet also elects to cast the Unicode character directly to ASCII, since the first 127 Unicode characters are defined to match ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

FieldOffset, maybe?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct struct1
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte a;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
        public int b;
    [FieldOffset(5)]
        public short c;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
        public byte[] buffer;
    [FieldOffset(18)]
        public byte d;
}
```

(c) http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/